# Deployment of java application to bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have created an java Application in Eclipse IDE.
Can anyone help out how to edit a Java application in Eclipse & trigger a deploy to Bluemix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official IBM Bluemix plugin for Eclipse can do this for you.

Grab it from the Eclipse Marketplace here: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-eclipse-tools-bluemix#.VHAf-1Xd9E4

Here is some documentation about the plugin: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-IBM_Eclipse_Tools_for_Bluemix

Once you install this, you should be able to connect your Bluemix account and package / deploy apps with the push of a button.

Answer (score 2):

You will find the steps by steps to see how you can deploy you app in bluemix. You can use CF API, or download the eclipse plugin. [Here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-hangman-app/index.html?ca=drs-&ce=ism0070&ct=is&cmp=ibmsocial&cm=h&cr=crossbrand&ccy=us) you can see how to use the CF API for Bluemix.

Basically you need three commands:

```
cf api bluemix_domain
cf login -u username
cf push appname -p appname.war
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get official eclipse plugin from IBM and deploy it to Bluemix.
Below is the link to download and get started on this:

```
https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-IBM_Eclipse_Tools_for_Bluemix
```